# I installed conky and I have few questions

Tags: 14.04, gnome, conky

So I just installed Conky, configured it in Terminal while it was almost finished. I set location, it's using the metric system, so it's really cool. But I have few questions:

1. Am I able to use 2 Conkys in the same time or set two cities as default?
2. How often does Conky updates itself? I mean on MyWeather Indicator app I could set 15 or 30 minutes and so on.
3. How does Conky Manager works? I installed it hoping that I can customize things like in Gnome Tweak or something like that but it's really different.
4. If you can't help with the manager then can you tell me the way you configure conky in terminal? Because with my Conky theme (Harmattan) I could/can choose from 4 versions and maybe later I'd like to change those modes. In the picture you see one of them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using more then one conky config same time**

You can use more than one  conky configuration at the same time. For this create a script.

For example using `gedit ~/.conky/startconky.sh`  create script file in ~/.conky directory.

Now add following content in it

```
       #!/bin/sh

        sleep 5

        conky -c <path_of_1st_conky_config_file> &
        conky -c <path_of_2nd_conky_config_file> &
        conky -c <path_of_3rd_conky_config_file> &

        exit
```

Make it ececutable using `chmod +x ~/.conky/startconky.sh` and add this script to your   **Startup Applications**.

**Now How conky update weather?**

Conky have `weather` object to get weather data.

From `man conky`

```
  weather URI locID data_type (interval_in_minutes)
          Download, parse and display METAR data.

          For the 'URI', there are two possibilities:

          http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/
          http://xoap.weather.com/weather/local/
```

It also  depends upon your configuration file how you are manipulating   weather data from the website. form more see `man conky` or visit [conky docs page](http://conky.sourceforge.net/docs.html) .

[**Conky-Manager**](https://launchpad.net/conky-manager)

[Conky manager](https://launchpad.net/conky-manager) is a GUI tool which is used to manage conky config file. It actually change various parameter available in the config file according to the option you have selected, like `gap_x`, `gap_y`, `alignment` etc.

If you want to change your conky configuration, open it with gedit and make changes whatever you need.